# Can we do "DELETE database name. table name" in hive latest version?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am using spark and executing HQL queries using HiveContext. I want to delete `table(student)` from `database(test)` in hive. So, will this command `delete test.student` will run in `hivecontext`.
    It can run in teradata so can i use it as it is in Hive(in spark).

Answer (score 6):

No, `"DELETE <database_name>.<table_name>"` is not supported in hive, as well in Spark. Instead, you can do the following:

```
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <db_name>.<table_name>");
```

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, without NOT. I could not edit your answer. It says: Edits can be at least 6 characters...

Comment: @SwapnilDixit Happy to help :)

Comment: If you DROP TABLE IF EXISTS like this, and your tables are stored as parquet (or maybe that doesn't matter) it looks like it still leaves the files on HDFS. Is there a scala/pyspark or sparkSQL way to clean up the tables & files at the same time? or just rm them after dropping them?